# How to check if application is closing in FXML controller

Tags: java, javafx-8

Is there any way how to check (and append event handler on it) if application is going to be closed in FXML controller (not main class derived from [Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) but controller attached to FXML file derived from [Initializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html))?

Thanks, help much appreciated.

Comment: If this is not possible and I should use `stop()` method in main class derrived from [Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) how pass data from FXML controller back to main class?

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do during the close?  Since the Controller could be backing a stage, or just a complicated node - it would help to understand your intent.

Comment: Save data to XML file (they are loaded when application starts, then populated into tableview) now I need to save changes.

Comment: Why does this need to be when the application is closing?  Could this happen when a stage closes?  Will there be different data if the application is still running but this controller is gone?

Comment: Yes, I think it could be when stage is closing - anyway application has just one window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should help you get where you need to be.

```
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent node = loader.load(getClass().getResource("myfxml.fxml")).openStream());
    Scene scene = new Scene(node);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    MyController controller = (MyController)loader.getController();

    stage.setTitle(titleString);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setOnHidden(event -> {
    //do all your processing here
         controller.doSaveHere();
    });
    stage.show();
```

However there are other hooks you could use - setOnHiding() or setOnCloseRequest()

Comment: As I told - I need it from FXML controller - this is obviously main class... I don't know if I have correct design (I'm loadinig data from XML in the FXML controller not in the main class - you can see sources in [GitHub](https://github.com/ondrejd/costs-javafx-app) - I do all things in `CostsController` class.

Comment: Please, either I need how to pass data to FXML controller from main class and back or I will have to rewrite `XmlDataSource` to hold data in static property and save them in main `Costs` class. And sorry for stupid questions - this is my first Java application.

Comment: You have a reference to your controller where you initialize the FXML as noted above, I edited it to show how you could invoke the save on your controller at that point.  There is no need to pass the data back to the MAIN class - just expose the API you need to call when the stage is closing.

Comment: Hi, there are some errors - 1) `loader.load("myfxml.fxml")` can not be - must be `loader.load(getClass().getResource("myfxml.fxml"))`. 2) error is now thrown when I'm closing application (I have `stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> { controller.test(); });` where `controller.test()` just prints message to standard output). Error is `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException`. And what is more important `controller.test()` is not called!

Comment: I fixed it - second line should be `Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("myfxml.fxml").openStream());`. Thanks anyway - you directed me to the right course! Thanks.

Comment: Better is to do `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("myfxml.fxml"));` and then `Parent root = loader.load();`.